# Disable previous days in default Magento2 calendar

Tags: magento2, datepicker, calendar

I have successfully added calender in my custom form by using below code.

```
<script>
                require([
                    "jquery",
                    "mage/calendar"
                    ], function($){

                        $("#My_ID").calendar({
                            showsTime: false,   
                            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
                            buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
                //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            }); 
                    });             
            </script>
```

But, How can I disable previous days in default magento2 calendar?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me step by step to add this script to from ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set your minDate or maxDate in order to limit your calendar.

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {

        $("#My_ID").calendar({
            showsTime: false,
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            buttonText: "<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
            minDate: new Date(),
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are always welcome brother

Comment: @akshay how to change date format and disable previous date

Comment: @akshay I am usign this for datepicker http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Comment: @pradeep: Magento calendar is the extended version of jQuery calendar , So you can use the properties available in jQuery calendar. Please follow below reference URL : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: @akshay Yes, I know but in which file need to add code for change format

Comment: @pradeep: I have edited my post to answer your query.

Comment: @akshay provide path of the file where to change

Comment: @akshay currently is showing date format mm/dd/yyyy, need to change in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @akshay for this which file to be chabge