# Magento 2: Disable past dates for the Datepicker built via ui-component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, form-validation, datepicker

I am trying to add a validation to the datepicker so that users won't be able to select past dates. The datepicker is built via ui-component and the code snippet is as follows:

[image]

I have checked this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99845/disable-previous-days-in-default-magento2-calendar/107186?newreg=7e912e8ce9574469ac4983abc31a8a9f) where in they have said to add the javascript in the template file but in our case we don't have any template file.
My case is similar to this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139711/validating-form-elements-built-via-ui-components) but not getting where to put the javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99845/disable-previous-days-in-default-magento2-calendar

Answer (score 5):

> **You can set this field in your ui-component**

```
<field name="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()+ 1</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: use <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item> so today date also showing.